# Report Data Not Displaying When populating the Data From DataSet

Tags: asp.net, telerik

[CrossPost]
I am trying to pass the Data from C# to Telerik Report. Initially i created a Web Project and I added Telerik Report to the Project. I followed a tutorial to create a Report and assign a Dataset to the Report. Here i will be designing a Report. I need to assign a Data To Report through a Datatable, which need to be populated in Report where we need to Map The Columns. On Page Load i am Trying to do this,

In My Page Load i written by Code as

Report2 objReport2 = new Report2();
                objReport2.DataSource = GetAllData();
                ReportViewer1.ReportSource = objReport2;
                ReportViewer1.DataBind();
                ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

From the above code, i am seeing the blank Report wihtout Data.
In Desinger i created a table, But i failed to create  a Mapping between Report And Dataset Column? May i know how do i do this? Or else can any one suggest me a scenario to resolve this?